# How to fix SMS app showing no message even though they are available through Spotlight?

Tags: iphone, sms

I was composing an SMS message and then I tapped on send button. This message was composed for group of 50 persons. It started sending messages in background and I could hear the sound of sending messages one by one.

Suddenly while sending messages, the Springboard crashed. It displayed me three options: "OK", "Restart", "Help". I tapped on "OK" and restarted SMS app to view SMS. But I found everything empty in SMS application and messages were still being sent from my phone in the background.

I got frustrated and I connected the iPhone to my computer, it started synchronizing and synchronized the empty SMSs.

I am able to search all of my previous messages from Spotlight search, but when I select a message from search results of spotlight, it redirects me to SMS application and application shows nothing.

Even in SMS application, I can search for messages and I can find the previous messages as a search result but I can't open them.

How can I get back my messages?

Comment: I assume you restarted your iPhone already?

Comment: @patrix - Yes !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must restore your iPhone from a iOS backup! But than you will lost your last changes.

Comment: I already restored the phone, but it restores from the last sync & during last sync - I lost all msgs. So, even after the restore, I have no messages. My Last last backup was before 2 months.

Comment: Sorry! But my English is not very well. You wrote in your quastion that you only sync your iPhone. A restore from a backup will replace your complete content on the iPhone and overwrite all changes since that backup.

Comment: I am able to view all the msgs from spot-light search even after restoring the iphone.